# How to encrypt a fixed size number using OpenSSL::Cipher

Tags: ruby, encryption, encoding, openssl

I need to encrypt a number using `OpenSSL::Cipher::AES`, however I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what combination of packing I need to use to get a known result.

I have Java reference code as follows:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs;

class Encryptor {
  private String initialVector;
  private static final String TRANFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
  private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";

  String encrypt(SecretKeySpec key, long timestamp) throws Exception {
    byte[] encryptedBytes = getEncryptingCipher(key).doFinal(Longs.toByteArray(timestamp));
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedBytes);
  }

  private Cipher getEncryptingCipher(SecretKeySpec key) throws
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
    InvalidKeyException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
      Cipher encryptingCipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANFORMATION);
      encryptingCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new
          IvParameterSpec(initialVector.getBytes()));
      return encryptingCipher;
  }

  private SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(String key) throws DecoderException {
    byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
    return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, ALGORITHM);
  }

  void setInitialVector(String initialVector) {
    this.initialVector = initialVector;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor();
    encryptor.setInitialVector("0000000000000000");
    //Expensive operation so only performed once, re-use the key spec instance
    SecretKeySpec keySpec =
    encryptor.getSecretKeySpec("b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80");
    long timestamp = 1464284796L; //System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String authToken = encryptor.encrypt(keySpec, timestamp);
    System.out.println(authToken);
  }
}
```

Which results in the following `base64` encoded string being printed on the console: `6BH3hg1cqQJOK6sG8gw7Xw==`

I've tried to replicate this using `OpenSSL::Cipher`, but I've had no luck. The Ruby OpenSSL documentation is lacking in detail. I suspect my use of pack is incorrect.

```
require "openssl"

key = ['b35901b480ca658c8be4341eefe21a80'].pack('H*')
iv  = '0000000000000000'
message = [1464284796].pack "N*"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
cipher.encrypt

cipher.iv  = iv
cipher.key = key

encrypted = cipher.update(message)
encrypted << cipher.final

cipher64 = [encrypted].pack('m')

puts "Generated: " + cipher64
puts "Expected : " + '6BH3hg1cqQJOK6sG8gw7Xw=='
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Guava documentation says for [`Longs#toByteArray(long)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html):

> `toByteArray(long value)`
>   Returns a big-endian representation of `value` in an 8-element byte array; equivalent to `ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(value).array()`.

but Ruby's [`Array#pack "N*"`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) encodes a 32-bit unsigned integer which results in 4 bytes. So, you could simply fill it up with 4 zeros:

```
message = [0, 1464284796].pack "N*"
```

or as [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214790/matt) notes in the comments using a big-endian 64-bit integer:

```
message = [1464284796].pack "Q>"
```

Comment: You could also use `Q>`, which would give you a 64 bit unsigned value directly without needing to add the extra zeros.